# Differentiation under integral sign when integral is over matrices not scalars? (Looking for Reference)

Tags: integration, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I am wondering about differentiation under the integral sign when the integral in question is actually over positive-definite matrices using the Haar invariante measure.
Suppose we have
\begin{eqnarray}
I(Y) = \int_{X>0} f(X,Y) (dX)
\end{eqnarray}
where $f$ is a well-behaved continuous, differentiable function of two (or more) arguments.
Suppose I wish to find $\frac{dI}{dY}$. We can also assume that $f$ is some analytic function like the trace or the exponential trace, those common in multivariate analysis.

Can someone point me to a standard reference or some formula in the style of
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign or perhaps show me how to arrive at this
?

Thanks so much!

Comment: There are two things that have to be cleared here: first, if your $f$ is not analytic on $[0,+\infty)$, then you have troubles with defining $f(X)$ for $X=X^\ast>0$. Second, what do you use as a measure on the set of positive definite matrices?

Comment: Also, you do not seem to have a parameter with respect to which you could take the derivative.

Comment: Thanks @TZakrevskiy and for helping me clarify the question.